# .gitignoreファイルをremote repoごとに設定したい

Tags: git

herokuを使って自作のアプリケーションをデプロイする際、作業リポジトリ(local)には自身のgitリポジトリと heroku のgit リポジトリの２つのリモートリポジトリが紐付けられており、同じ内容でpushすることは、現段階で可能なのですが、異なる内容(remote heroku のほうはすべてpushしたいが、remote originにはいくつかのファイルはpushしたくない)のpushを実現する方法はないのでしょうか.    
現在は内容の同じ2つのlocalリポジトリを作成し、それぞれにorigin,herokuのremote repo　を紐づけて一時的に対応しています。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

複数のリモートリポジトリで除外したいファイルがあるということは、
それぞれのリモートリポジトリにそれぞれのブランチがあるはずです。
それぞれのブランチで、.gitignoreを管理する事により、実現できるはずです。

たとえば、branch_aの.gitignoreでは

```
file_1
dir/file_2
```

branch_bの.gitignoreでは

```
file_1
dir/file_2
dir/file_3
```

など

Comment: 解答ありがとうございます。
現環境では、それぞれのremoteリポジトリにmasterブランチのみが存在するのですが、ブランチごとに.gitignore を管理というのは具体的に.gitignoreファイルをlocal リポジトリのどの部分に配置すればよいのでしょうか？
現在は、local リポジトリディレクトリの.git ディレクトリが存在する場所に配置しています。

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456533/is-there-a-way-to-setup-remote-specific-gitignores

こちらのpageを見つけ、私がしたいことと、まったく同じ質問なのですが、ここに示されている解決策が理解できません。

Comment: @berry_summerさん、その質問だと、もしかしてこれ [【初心者向け】railsアプリをherokuを使って確実にデプロイする方法【決定版】](https://qiita.com/kazukimatsumoto/items/a0daa7281a3948701c39) が参考になるかも？

Comment: @kunif さん　そちらの記事に目を通してみましたが、おそらく私の求めるものは載っていないようです。。
質問を抽象的に書いてしまったので、もう少し具体的に書きなおしておきます。

Comment: .gitignoreを置く場所はそこで良いと思います。
英語stackoverflowに書いてある解決策と私の言う解決策は同じ事を言っており、結局ブランチを複数持つしかない、という事です。
それぞれのリモートリポジトリにmasterブランチが存在したとしてもそれらは全く同じ内容であるべきです。同じmasterなのに中身が違うのであれば、それは別ブランチにすべきです。

Comment: @shirakia さん、おっしゃった通りbranchを分けることで、対応できました。しかし、まだbranchAからBに内容をmergeする際に、一部のfile(.gitignore など)を除外する方法については、まだ実現できていないため今一度調べてみようと思います。以下の方法ではうまくいかなかったので...もし、知っていれば教えてください。
https://qiita.com/matsuoshi/items/f40d60a5c0a1a169a73b